# ASP.NET Core IStartupFilter implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, lambda

I am currently learning ASP.NET Core and its features. One of its features is the `IStartupFilter` interface for use in the `Startup` method for registering middleware. I have this example implementation of the `Configure` method (entire class implementing this interface not shown) which injects a piece of custom middleware named `PrincipalInjectionMiddleware`:

```
            public Action<IApplicationBuilder> Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> next)
            {
                return builder =>
                {
                    builder.UseMiddleware<PrincipalInjectionMiddleware>();
                    next(builder);
                };
            }
```

I understand `Action<IApplicationBuilder>` encapsulates a method which does not return a value. Then why is the return statement above accepted as valid syntax and not this (the `_serviceProvider` variable comes from a constructor not shown here):

```
            public Action<IApplicationBuilder> Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> next)
            {
                IApplicationBuilder builder = new ApplicationBuilder(_serviceProvider);
                    builder.UseMiddleware<PrincipalInjectionMiddleware>();

                next(builder);
            }
```

The code above gives the error that not all code paths return a value. The code below doesn't work either since it's not possible to convert `void` to `Action<IApplicationBuilder>`:

```
            public Action<IApplicationBuilder> Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> next)
            {
                IApplicationBuilder builder = new ApplicationBuilder(_serviceProvider);
                    builder.UseMiddleware<PrincipalInjectionMiddleware>();

                return next(builder);
            }
```

My reasoning is that `Action<IApplicationBuilder>` is like `void` since it does not return a value. Is this a 'special' case? Is it possible to rewrite this method without a lambda expression? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is because the method called Configure returns an Action which just means a METHOD that takes IApplicationBuilder as parameter and returns void.

**Action** means method that returns void.

**Func** means method that returns something.

Action and Func are wrapper for "delegates" which are just "pointers" to methods.

**Delegates** are a way to store a method in a variable. To create a reference to a method that can be passed around and called in other places.

In other words they are syntactical sugar (more or less) for using delegates to store references to methods.

You could for example do this:

```
    public Action<IApplicationBuilder> Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> next)
    {
        var builder = new ApplicationBuilder(_serviceProvider);
        builder.UseMiddleware<PrincipalInjectionMiddleware>();

        next(builder);

        return next;//notice I am returning the ACTION not the return of the action
    }
```

Let me set a more clear example:

```
    public Action<IApplicationBuilder> Configure()
    {
        BuildAction(new ApplicationBuilder(_serviceProvider));//call the method

        return BuildAction;//return the actual method name... NOT a method call
    }

    //this method is being returned as a reference in the Configure method...
    private void BuildAction(IApplicationBuilder builder) 
    {
        builder.UseMiddleware<PrincipalInjectionMiddleware>();        
    }
```

See in the preceeding example I am returning an ACTUAL method... NOT a method call.

Comment: Thanks; I see my mistake now - this is what I was looking for. Funny thing is; I executed some Action<T> functions already but was thrown off guard by the 'return' statement in combination with the lambda expression.

Comment: @ArthurVisser if this helps you solve your question please mark as the answer.  Thank you.